# How to initialize an inherited object with either the 'usual' (keyword) arguments or an instance of the parent

Tags: python

I'd like to extend `datetime`'s `timedelta` class with a modulo operation. I'd also like to be able to initialize the resulting `TimeDelta` class in two ways:

1. By passing the (keyword) arguments that are usually passed to `timedelta`, e.g. `TimeDelta(seconds=5)`
2. By passing as an argument an instance of `timedelta`, in which case the `TimeDelta` 'takes over' the attributes of that instance.

I've tried the following:

```
import datetime

class TimeDelta(datetime.timedelta):
    """Extends datetime's timedelta class with a modulo operation."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        timedeltas = [arg for arg in args if isinstance(arg, datetime.timedelta)]
        if timedeltas:
            self = timedeltas[0]
        else:
            super(TimeDelta, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self.total_seconds() % other.total_seconds()
```

However, if I try to create an instance of `TimeDelta` in the first way, I get a `TypeError`:

```
In [1]: execfile('interval.py')

In [2]: time_delta = TimeDelta(datetime.timedelta(seconds=5))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a0e79564603f> in <module>()
----> 1 time_delta = TimeDelta(datetime.timedelta(seconds=5))

TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.timedelta
```

It seems like the `else` statement is being called immediately, which doesn't work because `timedelta` doesn't expect an instance of itself as an argument in its instantiation. Is this the case? If so, why isn't the `if` statement getting triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't go into your `__init__` at all. The timedelta class defines `__new__`, as you can see in [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L355), and the error occurs there - which is why you don't see your code in the traceback.

(Also note that `self = timedeltas[0]` doesn't do anything at all other than rebind the local name, so your code wouldn't work even if you got around the init problem.)

Comment: I don't quite understand how the `__new__` method gets called here. According to [this blog](http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/06/__new__-python/), it is called by 'calling the class', but in this case all I've done before the `__init__` is inherit from `datetime.timedelta`. I've done some examples without the `__init__` that seem to be instantiable without errors, so it seems to me that the error is associate with the presence of the `__init__`?

Comment: You call it when you instantiate a TimeDelta.