# In Python, how to create a subclass of datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, inheritance

I'd like to extend the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object of the `datetime` module with `__div__` and `__mod__` operations. I would like the resulting class `TimeDelta` to be initializable either with an ordinary `timedelta` as its first input argument, or with the usual keyword arguments for `timedelta` (e.g. `seconds=1`). However, I get stuck at the following:

```
import datetime

class TimeDelta(datetime.timedelta):
    def __init__(self, timedelta, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

td1 = TimeDelta(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3))
```

This leads to the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/dev/scratch/Furion_scheduler/extended_timedelta.py", line 7, in <module>
    td1 = TimeDelta(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3))
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: datetime.timedelta
```

which, as pointed out by Daniel Roseman in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743739/how-to-initialize-an-inherited-object-with-either-the-usual-keyword-argument), is because the `timedelta` object defines a `__new__` method (cf. its [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L355)).

One way around this problem is to use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class TimeDelta(object):
    def __init__(self, timedelta, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(timedelta, datetime.timedelta):
            self.timedelta = timedelta
        else:
            self.timedelta = datetime.timedelta.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __mod__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, datetime.timedelta):
            return self.timedelta.total_seconds() % other.total_seconds()
        elif isinstance(other, TimeDelta):
            return self.timedelta.total_seconds() % other.timedelta.total_seconds()

td1 = TimeDelta(datetime.timedelta(seconds=5))
td2 = TimeDelta(datetime.timedelta(seconds=2))

print td1 % td2
```

One not-so-elegant aspect of this, however, is that in the `__mod__` method one currently has to check whether the `other` is an instance of `timedelta` or `TimeDelta`.

Is there a way to either make the inheritance work, or to make the `TimeDelta` with composition such that if any method (such as `total_seconds()`) called on it is not defined, it tries to call the method on its `self.timedelta`?

**Update**

In the end, I found using composition easier than overriding the `__new__` method. I refactored the code above a bit by defining a `total_seconds()` method for `TimeDelta`:

```
class TimeDelta(object):
    def __init__(self, timedelta=None, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(timedelta, datetime.timedelta):
            self.timedelta = timedelta
        else:
            self.timedelta = datetime.timedelta(**kwargs)

    def total_seconds(self):
        return self.timedelta.total_seconds()

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self.total_seconds() % other.total_seconds()
```

This method would be cumbersome if `timedelta` had many methods which had to be 'referred to' in this way, but in this case `total_seconds()` is its only method (cf. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Comment: Call `super()`.