# can't inherit from timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was annoyed by the fact that [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) has no `__format__` method. so i wanted to inherit from `timedelta` (monkey-patching is no option for `built-in/extension type 'datetime.timedelta'`)

so i tired inheritance (`my_dict` is just here for reference; this one works!).

```
from datetime import timedelta

class my_dict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class my_timedelta(timedelta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

print(my_dict.__mro__)
# (<class '__main__.my_dict'>, <class 'dict'>, <class 'object'>)

print(my_timedelta.__mro__)
# (<class '__main__.my_timedelta'>,
#  <class 'datetime.timedelta'>, <class 'object'>)

d0 = my_dict(); d1 = my_dict(a=3)
print(d0, d1)
# -> {} {'a': 3}

# no arguments: this works!
t0 = my_timedelta()
print(t0)      # -> 0:00:00

# one argument: TypeError
# t1 = my_timedelta(5)  # -> TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
# print(t1)

# a key-word argument: TypeError
# t2 = my_timedelta(seconds=5)  # -> TypeError: object.__init__() 
#                                               takes no parameters
# print(t2)
```

the method resolution order of both looks similar; but it seems that `__init__` in the `timedelta` case is skipping `timedelta.__init__` and jumping directoy to `object.__init__`.

am i doing something very wrong? how can i inherit from `timedelta`? what goes wrong here?

Comment: `timedelta` has no `__init__`. Why do you need it if you only call the base initializer inside? I think that if you need to do some custom initialization, you should override the *ctor* (`__new__`).

Comment: @CristiFati oh, good point! that is indeed where i went wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [How to initialize an inherited object with either the 'usual' (keyword) arguments or an instance of the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743739/how-to-initialize-an-inherited-object-with-either-the-usual-keyword-argument?rq=1), you have to override `new()` method. Something like:

```
class my_timedelta(timedelta):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # whatever here
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: yup, thanks! did not realize `timedelta` has no `__init__`. should have noticed that from the error messages...